# Select an Average price from a selected product and echo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a databse of whiskies with sale prices over a period of time. In my database I have Name,Price Url and Id.

I have quite a few whiskies with the same name, but sale prices are different. Currently when someone does a search it takes them to the search results page that shows the product they have searched for.

What I am trying to do is when someone clicks the link to see the full details, I would like to be able to show the average price for all the whiskies that come under that name, but I am struggling as you can probably see. Its the ressult.php I am having the problem with all I am getting echoed is a £. I seem to have lost the name and url being echoed
and not getting the name url_img or Average price ( which i am trying to calculate. But my focus is to get the average price to show.

**Search.php**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE name LIKE :name ORDER BY name ASC"); // Use = instead of LIKE for full matching
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $search);  
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); // Added to count no. of results returned

if ($count >= 1) { // Only displays results if $count is 1 or more

    echo "<div class='results_found'>";
    echo $count; 
    echo " results found<br>";
    echo "</div>";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo "<div class='results'>";
        echo "<div class='result_name'>";
                echo "<b>Whisky Name:</b><br>";
                echo "<a href='details1.php?id={$row['lot_id']}' >{$row['name']}</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
} 

} else {
      echo " Sorry no records were found";
}

?>

**results.php**

    <?php

    $page='details';
    include('header.php');
    include ('navbar.php'); 
    include ('connect.php');

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT name , AVG(price) , url_img , price FROM test_db JOIN (SELECT name, AVG(price) as avprice FROM test_db GROUP BY name) avcalc USING (name)
    WHERE lot_id = :id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ 'id' => $_GET['id'] ] );
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $row['name'];
echo '<br>';
echo '£';
echo $row['price'];
echo '<br>';
echo "<img src='".$row ['url_img']."' /><br />";
echo $row['avg'];

}

    ?>
```

Comment: Is there a specific part of your code that you are running into problems with?  It saves time to tell us, otherwise we just have to search until we find something wrong.

Comment: Separate from the PHP code, please post a sample of the table's rows and a sample of what you would expect your query's output to be given those input rows. I notice you have no `GROUP BY` which will prevent the `AVG()` aggregate from functioning correctly.

Comment: please update you question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: I have update the question , trying to get the databse table to look correct.

Comment: I tried that code but it did not work , I have adjusted my code in the question and getting closer , but now all I get echoed is a £. Not sure where to go from here

Comment: You need to change your query to set the returned column value for AVG(price) to 'AVG(price) AS price'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$sql = "SELECT name 
        , price
        , url_img 
        , avprice 
        FROM test_db 
        JOIN (
            SELECT name
            , AVG(price) as avprice 
            FROM test_db 
            GROUP BY name
            ) avcalc USING (name)
        WHERE lot_id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ 'id' => $_GET['id'] ] );
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo "{$row['name']}<br>
    &pound;{$row['price']}<br>
    <img src='{$row['url_img']}'/><br>
    {$row['avprice']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT `name`, AVG(price) as avg_price FROM `whisky` GROUP BY `name`
```

Original table data:

[image: Original table]

Result for this question:

[image: Result]

If you want only one price you can extends this query for **WHERE name = `whisky`**

Avg is now in: $row['avg_price']

Comment: I have been working on it for a bit and edited my code above, but all i get echoed now is a £ , no name url etc.

Answer (score 0):

You appied **join** query but you are getting AVG(price) insteadof **avgprice** which presented in first table **test_db**.
You need to create alias name of another **test_db**. 
Change this line

`$sql = "SELECT name , AVG(price) , url_img , avprice FROM test_db JOIN (SELECT name, AVG(price) as avprice FROM test_db GROUP BY name) avcalc USING (name) WHERE lot_id = :id";`

To this

`$sql = "SELECT name , avcalc.avgprice , url_img , avprice FROM test_db JOIN (SELECT name, AVG(price) as avprice FROM test_db GROUP BY name) avcalc USING (name) WHERE lot_id = :id";`

Comment: What does the t1 mean .? Thats a new one to me.

Comment: @json i will give better explationcurrently i am mobile

Comment: @json in short t1 is alias name of table..which you want avg column

Comment: Ok thanks. I am ony mobile to. I just changed the code in the question as i somehow put avgprice in and it does not actually exist in my table.

Comment: It still just echoes out the £ sign and nothing else. In my table I just have        date ,  name , price ,url_sale  u,rl_img  l,ot_id

Comment: @Jason you can't "echo" or you can't "calculate avg()".i cant understand.please change the title.

Comment: @Jason after £ sign put  "echo $row['avprice'];" then it should be print